# How to get specific param value from the result of Fn::Sub on URL in AWS template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating many resources using the AWS CloudFormation template, and I have almost 30 tags that I need to attach with each resource as it's required for company standards. So attaching 30 tag lines for each resource is very difficult to maintain. So I was thinking of placing all the tags in one place and reuse.

So here, I created a `tags.yml` file, which contains all the tags and some of the values coming from environment variables and some of them are static:

```yaml
tags:
  - Key: A
  - Value: !Sub "${ENV_VAR}"
  - Key: B
  - Value: "Test Tag"
  ...
```

`main-stack.yml`

```yaml
WSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  ...
Resource:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      ...
    TemplateURL: !Sub "${S3_PATH}/resource.yml"
    Tags: !Sub "${S3_PATH}/tags.yml"
```

In the above code, I'm applying tags to the AWS CloudFormation Stack resource, and that `tags.yml` file has the property `tags`, which I need to get its value, how can that be done?

In `serverless.yml` of the serverless framework you can use the `file()` function like this `${file(tags.yml):tags}` to get the specific parameter, but is there any workaround in the AWS template? I tried to use `Fn::GetAttr` but it didn't work.